# PDOException with message 'could not find driver' Error for Laravel and Postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, apache

First of all, the problem is about Laravel not postgresql or PHP. I can connect postgresql with a simple PHP file. But Laravel can't do it somehow.

When I try to connect postgresql server in my computer with laravel I get "PDOException with message 'could not find driver'" error. I am getting this error when I run `DB::connection()->getPdo();` command at artisan tinker.

If I run `php artisan migrate` command, the error is `Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

My configuration is below:

- Windows 10
- Wamp Server 3.1.4
- Apache 2.4.35
- PHP 7.2.10
- Laravel Framework 6.0.3

Related lines of Laravel .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=laravel_dnm1
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=mrd.BE.265
```

Related lines of Laravel database.php file:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

...

```
    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

When I run `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` at my server I get below output:

> Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => pgsql [2] => sqlite )

Related lines of php info is below:

[image: Screenshot of phpinfo]

NOTE: There is no problem when I use mysql instead of postgresql.

NOTE2: I can connect the DB when I use regular PHP. Only Laravel gives this error.

Comment: Do you also define this driver in your models? Show us the code that triggers the error please?

Comment: I added how I get the error to second paragraph of the question. I have a model named Product also.

Answer (score 11):

install postgresql

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```

then uncomment pgsql and pdo-pgsql extensions in etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/apache2/php.ini file

then restart apache2

Comment: I have extension=pdo_pgsql and extension=pgsql in my php.ini file. They are already uncommented.

Answer (score 2):

Verify your PHP version with `php -v`

Install `php7.2-pgsql` when needed.

Comment: My PHP version is 7.2.10. I am using WAMP and activated pdo_pgsql and pgsql extensions.

Comment: In that case you should follow this guide on how to install php pgsql on WAMP https://www.carnaghan.com/knowledge-base/how-to-setup-postgresql-on-wamp-server/

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. It is a bug at WAMP I think. When I edit php.ini from WAMP's menu it opens a different php.ini than active PHP version's. So I opened php.ini from file system and edited it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are different php version installed on your WAMP SERVER. when you click on WAMP icon it will show that pgsql and pdo_pgsql are active but for different php version. You need to check your php version using php -v command and then go to the WAMP folder and find that php version and edit php.ini file and enable pgsql extensions there.